LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_log-vc143-mt-gd-x64-1_85.lib' in CMake project
I've encountered this problem: linker cannot find Boost.Log library which clearly does exist in destination. I use MS Visual Studio 2022, so my compiler surely is msvc143 as stated in library.
I have environment variables set like this:

And my CMakeLists.txt is:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(SMTPLogger)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

find_package(Boost 1.85 REQUIRED COMPONENTS log thread)
if(Boost_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "Boost include directories: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
    message(STATUS "Boost libraries: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARYDIR})
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find Boost")
endif()

find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

add_executable(Logger src/Logger.cpp main.cpp)
target_include_directories(Logger PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(Logger Boost::log Boost::thread Threads::Threads)

When building, CMake outputs next message:
1> [CMake] CMake Warning at C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1398 (message):
1> [CMake]   New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
1> [CMake]   targets
1> [CMake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
1> [CMake]   C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1523 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
1> [CMake]   C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2135 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
1> [CMake]   CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)

In message(STATUS "Boost libraries: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}") there is no libboost_log-vc143-mt-gd-x64-1_85.lib:
1> [CMake] -- Boost include directories: C:/dev/utilities/boost_1_85_0
1> [CMake] -- Boost libraries: optimized;C:/dev/utilities/boost_1_85_0/stage/lib/boost_log-vc143-mt-x64-1_85.lib;
debug;C:/dev/utilities/boost_1_85_0/stage/lib/boost_log-vc143-mt-gd-x64-1_85.lib;
optimized;C:/dev/utilities/boost_1_85_0/stage/lib/boost_thread-vc143-mt-x64-1_85.lib;
debug;C:/dev/utilities/boost_1_85_0/stage/lib/boost_thread-vc143-mt-gd-x64-1_85.lib;
optimized;C:/dev/utilities/boost_1_85_0/stage/lib/boost_log_setup-vc143-mt-x64-1_85.lib;
debug;C:/dev/utilities/boost_1_85_0/stage/lib/boost_log_setup-vc143-mt-gd-x64-1_85.lib;
optimized;C:/dev/utilities/boost_1_85_0/stage/lib/boost_filesystem-vc143-mt-x64-1_85.lib;
debug;C:/dev/utilities/boost_1_85_0/stage/lib/boost_filesystem-vc143-mt-gd-x64-1_85.lib;
optimized;C:/dev/utilities/boost_1_85_0/stage/lib/boost_regex-vc143-mt-x64-1_85.lib;
debug;C:/dev/utilities/boost_1_85_0/stage/lib/boost_regex-vc143-mt-gd-x64-1_85.lib;
optimized;C:/dev/utilities/boost_1_85_0/stage/lib/boost_chrono-vc143-mt-x64-1_85.lib;
debug;C:/dev/utilities/boost_1_85_0/stage/lib/boost_chrono-vc143-mt-gd-x64-1_85.lib;
optimized;C:/dev/utilities/boost_1_85_0/stage/lib/boost_atomic-vc143-mt-x64-1_85.lib;
debug;C:/dev/utilities/boost_1_85_0/stage/lib/boost_atomic-vc143-mt-gd-x64-1_85.lib

As seen below, library is located in ${BOOST_LIBRARYDIR} path.

As I researched the question, I realised that I cannot go to Configuration Properties and further, as there are none shown for CMake project. I`ve tried rebuilding, clearing CMake cache but nothing worked.
I suppose the problem may lay in Boost version that I am currently using, 1.85.0, and CMake version 3.28.3
Thank you in advance.

Note: There is no reason to check Boost_FOUND variable, if you use keyword REQUIRED with the find_package. Would that search fails, CMake itself will terminate configuration.

@Tsyvarev okay thanks i didn`t know that

Have you tried to set BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK macro, as suggested in the question/answer pair? You may set this macro either in your source file, before inclusion of Boost headers, or in your CMakeLists.txt by using target_compile_definitions command.

Try adding log_setup to your list of components COMPONENTS log_setup log thread) I recall something like this myself and that was the solution. A long shot and probably wrong of course, but easy to try.

The CMake output you posted shows that CMake does find Boost libraries, as they are present in Boost_LIBRARIES. It may be missing alias targets such as Boost::log though. Could you show the linker command line and the error message?

I suspect, CMake doesn't use the CMake config files that are produced by Boost build process. Those files are normally placed in <BOOST_ROOT>/stage/lib/cmake. You can see the list of paths CMake uses to search for config files here. You can try setting CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH environment variable to <BOOST_ROOT>/stage/lib/cmake and see if that helps.

When use find_package(Boost), it defines special target Boost::dynamic_linking. Linking with that target automatically defines BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK macro, which is needed for use dynamic Boost libraries on Windows:
target_link_libraries(Logger Boost::log Boost::thread Boost::dynamic_linking Threads::Threads)


I fixed this by adding #include <boost/config/user.hpp> to the header file. In user.hpp I enabled (uncommented) the #define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK, which

...forces all libraries that have separate source,to be linked as dll's rather than static libraries on Microsoft Windows (this macro is used to turn on __declspec(dllimport) modifiers, so that the compiler knows which symbols to look for in a dll rather than in a static library).  Note that there may be some libraries that can only be linked in one way (statically or dynamically), in these cases this macro has no effect.

And it solved my problem. I have read that this macro can also be defined through CMakeLists.txt file, by adding
set_target_properties(Boost::dynamic_linking PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK")

but user.hpp variant appears more convenient to me.
